# Using for loop to create scatterpolar subplot with Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, scatter-plot, radar-chart

I want to create Scatterpolar (subplot) with Plotly, the plot shows information about 2 players.

Here is my code.

```
def Polar(Player_data, Selected_Player_data):
    
    data_copy = Selected_Player_data.copy().iloc[0:1,:-3]

    # select player
    name = data_Sample[data_Sample["Player"] == Player_data]
    # select features in data_sample dataset
    feature = name[[i for i in data_copy.columns.tolist()]]
    
    data = pd.concat([feature, data_copy])
    
    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,specs=[[{"type": "Polar"},{"type": "Polar"}]])

    for i in data.columns[1:]:
        if max(data[i]) < 50:
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
                  r = [feature[i].values[0]],
                  theta = [i],
                  fill = 'toself',
                  marker_color='rgb(47,138,196)',
                  name = Player_data),row=1, col=1)
                
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
                  r = [data_copy[i].values[0]],
                  theta = [i],
                  fill = 'toself',
                  marker_color='rgb(237,100,90)',
                  name = Selected_Player_data.Player.values[0]),row=1, col=1)
        else:    
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
                  r = [feature[i].values[0]],
                  theta = [i],
                  fill = 'toself',
                  marker_color='rgb(47,138,196)',
                  name = Player_data),row=1, col=2)
                
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
                  r = [data_copy[i].values[0]],
                  theta = [i],
                  fill = 'toself',
                  marker_color='rgb(237,100,90)',
                  name = Selected_Player_data.Player.values[0]),row=1, col=2)


    fig.layout.update(
        go.Layout(
        polar = dict(
            radialaxis = dict(
                visible = True,)),
        showlegend = True,
       
        height=400, width=1000,
        ))
    
    return py.iplot(fig)

Polar('J. Sands', data_JSands)
```

After running this function, I got this.
[image]

There are two questions.

1. Why are there only dots in the plot?
2. Why are there many legends?

Comment: I have not used the polar coordinate type for scatter plots very often, but as far as I can tell from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/polar-chart/#categorical-polar-chart), the r-values are in list form. Are the values specified in list form? The reason for the many duplicate legends is that you are specifying NAME in the loop process. The countermeasure should be to specify name only for zero in the loop counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of markers by:

```
fig.update_traces(mode = 'lines')  # you can also change it to "markers+lines"
```

There is a legend for each subplot in the grid. If all legends are the same, you can solve this problem by adding this attribute to all subplots except the last one.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
                  r = [data_copy[i].values[0]],
                  theta = [i],
                  fill = 'toself',
                  marker_color='rgb(237,100,90)',
                  showlegend= False,    #<--------- Add to all subplots except the last one
                  name = Selected_Player_data.Player.values[0]),row=1, col=1)
```